# SQL query: count for all the reviews that each customer has written

Tags: sql

Lets say I have one table called "REVIEWS"

This table has Reviews that customers have written for various products.

I would like to be able to get a "count" for all the reviews that each customer has written,
so I write:

```
SELECT count(*) AS counter
FROM reviews 
WHERE customers_id = 12345
```

Now, my problem is that I wish to have a count like above BUT only for customers who have written a SPECIFIC product review

For instance,

```
SELECT customers_review
FROM reviews
WHERE
products_id = '170'
```

In summary, I wish to be able to get the customers TOTAL COUNT for every review they have written, but ONLY for customers who have written a review for a specific product.

Comment: thank you all for helping me out, you guys rock!

Comment: @Sebastian, now that you've had your question answered, maybe you could edit your subject line to something a little more specific? I hate to think how many questions here have this same subject line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select customers_id, count(*)
from reviews
where customers_id in 
(select customers_id from reviews where products_id = '170')
group by customers_id;
```

Comment: exists is going to be faster than in

Comment: Carl, thanks for your suggestion but as a side note, this query you suggested to me (as well as the EXISTS variation) takes quite a bit of time 8 - 14 seconds to query on my MYSQL site, do you think there is any possibility of optimizing this to make it faster? thanks...

Comment: Sebastian, if reviews has an index on customers_id, I think this is about as fast as it can be; I don't think IN versus EXISTS is likely to make a difference.  If reviews doesn't have an index, of course, add one.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT customers_id, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM reviews 
WHERE customers_id IN(
SELECT customers_id
FROM reviews
WHERE
products_id = '170'
)
GROUP BY customers_id
```

This will pull any customer who wrote about product X, and then count up total number of reviews they posted.

Comment: Damn you 27 second difference, this is almost word for word! LOL

Answer (score 1):

Just add to the end of your first query

> ```
> WHERE EXISTS (
> SELECT 1 FROM reviews AS r 
> WHERE r.customers_id = reviews.customers_id 
>     AND product_id = '170')
> GROUP BY reviews.customers_id
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select customer_ID, Count(*)
FROM reviews
WHERE customer_ID in ( Select Customer_ID from reviews where products_id = '170')
Group By customer_ID
```

This should give you a list of all CustomerID's along with the Count of all their reviews, but it will limit it only to the customers who have left a review for product 170.

Comment: Ian: I voted up both answers that were identical but faster than me :P

Answer (score 0):

Not disagreeing with the approaches in this thread.  But I think windowing/analytic SQL offer another way of looking at this problem.  You can get the counts:

- Count of Reviews by Customer on this
  detail row
- Count of Reviews By
  product on this detail row
- Count of
  Reviews by this customer on this
  product on this detail row
- Any
  details (the text of the review, the
  review ID etc...)

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT
 revid, 
 CUSTID, 
 PRODID,
 COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY custid) ByCust,
 COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY prodid) ByProd,
 COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY prodid, custid) ByCustProd

FROM customer_reviews
ORDER BY custid, prodid
```

**--OUTPUT--**

```
1520  106  1900 16  604 3
4650  106  1900 16  604 3
2730  106  1900 16  604 3
4640  106  3900 16  254 1
6287  110  1900 28  604 2
5849  110  1900 28  604 2
5965  110  3900 28  254 2
6117  110  3900 28  254 2
```